# Java - As Method or Inner Class or Class?

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes, actionlistener

So I've stumbled across several ways of implementing an ActionListener and I'm wondering if someone can walk me through the differences of how each works and whether there are reasons or advantages to use one over the other?

The first is below in a block of code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
// CODE HERE
}
```

The second way I saw was within another block of code as:

```
private class myListener implements ActionListener {
// CODE HERE
}
```

The third was is simply having a separate class for the ActionListener, with similar code to that above, but within a separate class.

I'm wondering whether the method approach is more efficient as new objects don't have to be created for each, you simply reference `this` as the ActionListener rather than, for example, referencing `new myListener()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference in speed in any of the options; you'll always have an object that implements the ActionListener interface. Avoiding an instance of a separate class will just save you a few bytes of memory.

Your choice really should be based on what makes sense for your code, structurally. For example, having your public class implement ActionListener may look weird for those who are using that class, especially if the ActionListener behavior is supposed to be private to the class and not used outside it.

So it's mostly a choice of what you think looks better in your code; the only real difference will be with regards to field / method access (e.g. a separate, non-inner class won't have access to private methods and fields of your class, an anonymous inner class can't access non-final variables of the enclosing method, etc).

Comment: And BTW, The statement "...an anonymous inner class can't access non-final variables of the enclosing method..." is a ++plus in my mind.

Comment: A class nested - whether or not anonymous - inside a method can not access non-final variables of the enclosing method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like or use "implements ActionListener".

I do like and use anonymous inner classes like:

```
    btnPurplescreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color baseColor = Color.BLUE;
            panelImage.setBackground(baseColor);
            panelReference.setBackground(baseColor);
            panelReference2.setBackground(baseColor);
            baseType = BaseType.PURPLE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: And the reason is the handler code is right near the object when it comes time to debug which means I have less searching to do because I do spend alot of time searching for bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You're stumbling in more ways that one.

In some sense, there is only one way to create a listener: there must be an object of a class that implements `ActionListener`, which means the class has the `actionPerformed` method.

There are three ways to do this:

You can modify a class you are already using for something else by marking it as implementing `ActionListener` and adding the `actionPerformed` method.  This saves you creating a new class -- a savings of negligible value in most cases -- but mars otherwise perfectly good code.  A few cases, when the existing

You can create a new *named* class.  This is useful if you think the name is going to be meaningful to someone.  If you are really using names like "MyListener", that's a clue that no, no-one cares about the name.

Finally, and usually, you can create an unnamed class.  If all you want to do is add a fragment of code as a listener.

Whatever your choice, it's *extremely* unlikely to have any detectably effect on the time or memory performance of your finished system.  The choice should be dictated by concerns about readability and maintainability.